# Understanding the algorithm behind day of week calculation

Tags: algorithms

I came across this algorithm recently to calculate day of the week for any year.

```
int y0 = year - (14 - month) / 12;
int x = y0 + y0/4 - y0/100 + y0/400;
int m0 = month + 12*((14 - month)/12) - 2;
int d0 = (date + x + (31*m0)/12)%7;
switch (d0) {
    case 1: return "Monday";
    case 2: return "Tuesday";
    case 3: return "Wednesday";
    case 4: return "Thursday";
    case 5: return "Friday";
    case 6: return "Saturday";
    case 0: return "Sunday";
}
```

How does this algorithm work? I see a lot of magic numbers in calculations above, but its difficult to understand the intuition behind this algorithm

Comment: if it written in c, dose month and year are int and start from zero or not (this might sound silly though)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, this program is a variant on [Zeller's congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence).

Here are the steps:

0. It's good to know that the Gregorian calendar (which is what we are using) repeats every 400 years. In the 400 year cycle, every fourth year is a leap year except for the centuries other than the one at the start of the cycle. In other words, in the 400-year cycle starting 2000 and ending 2399, there are 97 leap years: all the years divisible by 4 except 2100, 2200 and 2300.

   There are 365 days in a normal year, which is 52 weeks and one day. A leap year has an extra day. So the 400-year cycle, which has 303 normal years and 97 leap years, is 52*400 weeks plus (303 + 97*2 = 497) days. 497 days is exactly 71 weeks, so the cycle is an exact number of weeks, which means the weekday for a given date is the same for the "same date" in every cycle. (The same date meaning the same day, month and year mod 400.)

   Since we're only interested in which weekday a date is, and not the total number of days since some determined starting point, we can do all computations mod 7. So if we know the weekday for some particular date, we can find the weekday for the same day/month in another year by adding the number of years and then the number of intervening leap days.

   ```
    int x = y0 + y0/4 - y0/100 + y0/400;
   ```

   `y0` is explained below; if you think of it as the number of years from the beginning of (some) 400 year-cycle, then `x` is just the number of years plus the number of leap years: `y0/4` (every fourth year) `- y0/100` (except for centuries) + `y0/400` (other than the centuries which start a cycle). If we had computed `y0` as years into the current cycle, we could have avoided the `y0/400` term.
1. The fact that a leap day falls into the middle of a year complicates that computation. To make it simpler, we start the cycle at March 1 instead of January 1, effectively moving January and February to the previous year. That puts the leap day at the end of the year, so we can evaluate the number of leap days by counting the number of leap years, as above. As we'll see below, this also has the advantage of making the alternation of month lengths more regular; aside from February, months more or less alternate between 31 and 30 days.

   ```
    int y0 = year - (14 - month) / 12;
    int m0 = month + 12*((14 - month)/12) - 2;
   ```

   Those lines are trying to way too hard to be clever, and end up being terrible because of the slowness of division (even though division by 12 can be performed with multiplies, and even though the compiler can figure out that it's only necessary to do it once. The code would be clearer and faster if it were written in the obvious way:

   ```
    int y0 = year, m0 = month - 2;
    if (m0 < 1) { --y0; m0 += 12; }
   ```
2. Essentially, we now have a weekday offset of March 1 in the specified year from the March 1 which starts the cycle. Now we just need to figure out the adjustment for the months between March and the specified month. Each of these months will move the weekday by either two (30 mod 7) or three (31 mod 7) days. Months mostly alternate between 31 and 30 days, except although sometimes there are two 31-day months in a row. (As mentioned above, we can ignore February here because we're only counting months which come before the specified date, and with February shifted to the end of the year, it is never before any date in the year.)

   ```
    int d0 = (date + x + (31*m0)/12)%7;
   ```

   `(31 * m0) / 12` for `m0` in the range `[1, 12]` produces the sequence `{2, 5, 7, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 23, 25, 28, 31}`. The adjacent differences in that sequence are `{3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3}` which happen to correspond to the lengths of the months (mod 7) starting at March. (The pairs of consecutive 3s correspond to July/August and December/January.) So adding this to the year adjustment `x` and the date in the month `date` and then reducing the sum mod 7 gives us the day in the week with the week starting three days before March 1 of (every) cycle. (Three days before because (1) the magic formula `(31 * m0) / 12` starts with 2, not 0, and (2) the day of the month starts with 1, not 0. So the formula is off by 3.)

   This is not the only way of performing this calculation. As it happens, exactly the same sequence is produced with `(13 * m0 - 1) / 5`. Either way, the cleverness is not justified by efficiency; division is a lot slower than a simple table lookup:

   ```
    /* Not optimal but it corresponds to the above computation */
    static const char month_adjust[] = { 
        2, 5, 7, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 23, 25, 28, 31
    };
    int d0 = (date + x + month_adjust[m0]) % 7;
   ```

   The above table could be reduced to three bits per month, since only the value mod 7 is important. That means that the lookup table could be replaced with a magic integer constant and a bit-shift, but the potential gain is probably insignificant. I'll leave the details as an exercise for would-be code golfers.
3. March 1 of every cycle is a Wednesday, and that needs to correspond to the value 3 of that computation. The mapping between modulo and day of the week is provided by the switch statement:

   ```
    switch (d0) {
        case 1: return "Monday";
        case 2: return "Tuesday";
        case 3: return "Wednesday";
        case 4: return "Thursday";
        case 5: return "Friday";
        case 6: return "Saturday";
        case 0: return "Sunday";
    }
   ```

   I would have used a lookup table instead of a switch, which leads to more direct code:

   ```
    static const char* weekdays = { 
        "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday", "Thursday",
        "Friday", "Saturday"
    };
    return weekdays[d0];
   ```

Comment: Very nice! It may be worth to mention it is Zeller formula.

Comment: `if (m0 < 1) { ++y0; m0 += 12; }` Typo? I think the line should be `if (m0 < 1) { --y0; m0 += 12; }` to match the original formula.

Comment: @Explorer09: nice catch, thanks.

Comment: Just another note: The floor division magic (for `month_adjust`) in Zeller's algorithm might be preferred to table lookup for smaller code size. As the day of week is not calculated often, I would personally choose smaller code size. You might disagree, but both glibc and Android/Bionic seem to use floor division.

Comment: @Explorer09: I'm not sure which glibc code you are referring to. It uses both strategies in different places. There is [this use of Zeller's algorithm](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/tzset.c;h=a06142bb58b290e1a36d2b1ada98eb8784a8c818;hb=HEAD#l480) in `tzset`, which interprets the time zone initialization string. But in [`strptime`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/strptime_l.c;h=a3c5681fc2d154ea05caa041269faf4d91f5de5f;hb=HEAD#l210), it uses a lookup table. `mktime` avoids the issue entirely by effectively recomputing the weekday from the time_t.

Comment: Anyway, why would you assume that the lookup table results in longer code? Seems to me that the code is quite a bit shorter, and the lookup table itself only adds 13 bytes or so, depending on padding. (Could have been 12, but I added a blank entry at the beginning to avoid a `- 1` in the code).

Comment: Implementations on Godbolt: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qaEfWK8s4

Comment: @rici 1. Thanks for additional info about glibc. I was referring to `tzset` code which is used when converting a `time_t` to a `struct tm` object. I didn't realize `strptime` has a duplicate function (for me it looks like an oversight for having two functions for the same thing).

Comment: @rici 2. I think the code size comparison would be fairer if you implement the functions like this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/54Y4M19n5

Comment: @explorer09: OK, that's fair. So if you compile with GCC using `-Os`, then the zeller code is only four bytes longer than my LUT code, which isn't quite enough to pay for the LUT. But other compilers, or GCC with different optimization settings, will change the DIV instructions to equivalent multiply and shift sequences, which are a little longer and much faster. With those settings, my code is both faster and shorter; with GCC and `-Os`, it is only faster. I could be wrong, but I don't think you'll find a popular distribution which compiles glibc with `-Os`.

Comment: Anyway, the code in `tzset.c` which is labelled as using Zeller's congruence is actually trying to interpret time zone change rules of the form "Change to summer time at 1 a.m. on the first Sunday of October" (example from `man tzset`; I live in a country which doesn't have annual time zone changes). You don't need Zeller to compute the day of the week from a `time_t`. Since the `time_t` is seconds since epoch, you just need `(t / 86400) % 7 + 4`; the +4 corresponds to the fact that the Unix epoch was a Thursday.

Comment: @rici You didn't address the size of the lookup table (`day_of_week[]`) in your code example comparing to my code example (the `zeller2()` function). By adding the size of the table, your code is larger. (Since you declare it as `static` the table would be placed separately from your function code. If you remove the `static` GCC would bring the table into the function body (as a series of `movq` instructions) and the code size can be compared fairer.)

Comment: @Explorer09; the table is 13 bytes. I've said that several times. When I do the comparison, I add 13 to the code size. It's hardly an extravagance.

Comment: @rici: Is there something different with how I calculate the size? (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/54Y4M19n5 ) `dowlut()`: 401263h - 401216h + 0Dh = 5Ah; `zeller2()`: 4012b8h - 401263h = 55h

Comment: @Explorer09: in practice, there will be padding but that's a bit unpredictable. Those are the same sizes I got, give or take a byte or two, and that's what I based my comment on, when I said that if you compile with gcc using -Os, the slightly shorter lut code is not saving enough to pay for the table. But, as I also said, if you compile with -O2, which much more common, or if you use a different compiler, the lut code is short enough to more than compensate. Also -O2 is a lot faster (and you might not care about this interface, but there are plenty more library interfaces.)